# Regex for space separated strings that cannot start with underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate list of tags - strings separated with space. Examples:

```
"blue white   green123 #$#! ()!!!123  q_w_e_r_t_y"
```

The only requirement is that they cannot start with an underscore '_'. What is an appropriate regex expression to match those tags?

I wrote some test case to verify the correctness of the pattern:

```
public void RegexTest()
{
    //arrange
    const string pattern = @"^PATTERN$";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var positive = new[] { "AAA", "A_", "AAA AAA", "AAA_AAAA", "AAA_AA AAA_aaa AA___   AAA", "A____", "333A%#$%#@%$__=-21-2-AA213", "+=-_0987654321`!@#$%^&*() qwertyu:/.," };
    var negative = new[] { "_AAAA", "A _AA ", "AA _AA", "A B _C", "_ " };

    //act
    var positiveMatches = positive.Select(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToArray();
    var negativeMatches = negative.Select(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToArray();

    //assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(positiveMatches.Select(x => true).ToArray(), positiveMatches);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new bool[negativeMatches.Length], negativeMatches);
}
```

Comment: AA _AA should this be rejected or AA should be returned

Comment: It should be rejected since it contains a tag starting with an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead to check for undescores preceeded by not of space or starting anchor.

```
^(?:(?!\s_|^_).)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH7pG6/10)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!^_)(?!.*?\s_\w)^.*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/5

Comment: Why it matches `A B _C`?

Comment: Updated pattern: (?!^_)(?!.*?\s_\w)^.*$ works. Thanks for the effort. +1 granted.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
^(?!(.*\s+)?_\w*\b).+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vJ1cP1/1)